# insert special charactar into oracle database and retrieve from java

Tags: java, oracle

I want to insert special character "triangle filled with black color and question mark inside it"  into oracle database and later retrieve from Java.

I am not able to insert into oracle DB table.

When I copy this special character "triangle filled with black color and question mark inside it" and paste into oracle sql editor to insert statement I am seeing square box like sign [].

```
 insert into mytable values (1,[]);  //like this here it is not copying exact character.
```

Is is related to oracle sql editor character encoding or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Best you go by the Unicode number to find the real problem, create the String u-escaped like `"\uFFFD"` or such. If you then dump  the code points of the re-retrieved string, you can check whether all went right. Without bothering of conversions and fonts at every point.

Comment: Thanks Joop. You mean to say I need to find unocode for my special character and then I insert that unicode into database ? e.g. http://unicode-table.com/en/#29EB  from this url I taken one sample special characetr and found its unicode as U+29EB. So to insert into DB table do I need to do as , insert into mytable values (1,"\U+29EB") ???

Comment: Using "\u29EB" already prevents the java compiler using an other encoding than the editor and the paste from the operating system. 3 Problems less for testing. The same using a numerical dump of the retrieved String. Those are measures for nearing the real error. (In general you will want to insert Unicode text as "ĉarma ĵaluza ŝi".)